# Cannot edit GPU from BIOS

Tags: linux, windows, bios, nvidia-graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I want to turnoff my NVIDIA graphics card from the BIOS itself on my Lenovo Legion Y530.

I found nothing in Linux nor in Windows that permits me from such thing. For example in Linux, blacklisting in `modprob` or uninstalling the driver didn't change the fact that NVIDIA is still consuming power. And if I want to save such power, I need to turn it off from the BIOS itself.

I tried to edit it form the BIOS menu (using <kbd>F12</kbd>) but simply there is no such option to turn off that NVIDIA peripheral completely (like other dell devices or even other Lenovo products).

How can I control any peripheral in my laptop without "physically disconnecting it"?

Comment: As long as you have the correct Nvidia drivers installed you also have Nvidia X Server Settings. There you can select the desired profile, Nvidia or Intel. Select the iGPU Intel and reboot, the dGPU is automatically turned off.

Comment: In Windows it toggles graphics automatically on-demand. Most of the time it'll be using the iGPU.

Comment: @ChanganAuto as a matter of fact, that is not true. i believed in this case "the toggling" for 3 years until i found out that even if the driver is uninstalled and not completely used by the system, it must be sleeping but not "turned off" thus, it consumes power even if it is uninstalled or modprobed.

Comment: What did you found out exactly?

Comment: What happens in Windows if in Device Manager > Display adaptors, you right-click the GPU and select Disable device? If this helps, it can also be done via the command-line.

Comment: I further disable it from Services to ensure that it is not working, but just connect it to an HDMI and it will work smooth as butter (indicating that it is just sleeping, nothing more); the peripheral sleeping means it is still consuming power (specifically 4.2 watt/h where the rest of my device consumes 0.8-1 watt/h), if NVIDIA is working (not sleeping) then it consumes 17-18 watt/h.

Comment: What you want is simply not possible.  Your not going to be able to “turn off” a mobile GPU after it’s been turned on, and you have to turn it on, in order to turn it off.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry? it is quite possible AFAIK, this fact is obtained form an advice that was given to me and some tutorials that illustrate how to do such thing in other products (laptops or Desktop), the thing is, it is not that simple in my case. so please illustrate more "how this is not possible".

Comment: Disabling the GPU is different from turning it off, so it draws no power, your speaking to an electrical engineer

Comment: @Ramhound despite im electrical engineering too, but i am not certain about what you said. All i want -whatever it is called- is to make it consume no power.